# Функция вкладок навигации

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая меняет блоки при нажатии на вкладку навигации...

```
function openCity(cityName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Помогите редактировать функцию для того чтобы при обновлении страницы все блоки были закрыты и только при нажатии на вкладку открывался соответствующий блок.

ps на данный момент при обновлении страницы блоки изначально открыты

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в стилях должно быть что-то вроде

```
.city:first-child {
 display: block;
}
```

удали это. также у первой вкладки должно быть что-то похожее

Answer (score 1):

```
.city {
 display: none;
}
```

правильный ответ